# DateTime-local how to prevent keyboard from appearing in android webview

Tags: android, cordova, datetime, webview, keyboard

I currently have a cordova android application that uses the following html5 tag:

```
 <input type="datetime-local"/>
```

On android this triggers the keyboard to show up.  However, I want to disable the keyboard because it doesn't make sense because the widget itself is sufficient.  You don't need the keyboard showing.

However, I can't figure out how to disable the keyboard from popping up.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

Add "readonly" attribute to your input tag. It will prevent the triggering of keyboard.

Comment: That will completely disable the datetime widget.  I want to still be able to use the widget without enabling the keyboard.